# Google Maps Error: Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I just started getting this error today for Google Maps:

Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property

I haven't changed any code in months.

The error is happening on this page:
http://gusmodern.com/pages/store-locator

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: start by loading the release-version of the maps-API(currently you load the experimental version). The URL of the V3-release-version is always `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3`

Answer (score 3):

I updated to the specific version reference https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true and the error went away.  I had this across multiple of my geolocation websites and mobile apps.

Comment: Yes, it worked for us also. It seems that Google updated their maps library recently.

Comment: I am again getting the same error don't know why. Above solution is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error just recently in some of my code. Thanks to another question in the past, I realized that when I set the markers I needed to make sure the variables I was bringing in for the anchor and scaled size were float numbers and not coming in as strings. This must be a new requirement with a recent update.

In my own code I changed

```
currentIcon = {
            url: 'http://www.example.com/img/avatars/'+name+'.png',
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(aw,ah),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(w,h)
        };
```

to

```
currentIcon = {
            url: 'http://www.example.com/img/avatars/'+name+'.png',
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(parseFloat(aw),parseFloat(ah)),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(parseFloat(w),parseFloat(h))
        };
```

and it now works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since two days I also experienced this problem. In my case I am setting a MarkerImage on the map with a null argument. This means that I am hiding markers on the map.

This worked before:

```
markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(null)
            });
```

Now this seems the solution:

```
markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            markers.setVisible(false);
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This will hide the whole marker.

If you want to hide just the icon:

`var nullIcon = {
    url: '',
    size: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: nullIcon, ...`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with an icon as property of a MarkerWithLabel{}.

The Solution:

```
var nullIcon = { url: '', size: new google.maps.Size(0, 0), origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) };
```