# Google Map:- InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I am getting this error in google maps.

**Error: InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property**

Earlier it was working fine and i never changed my code.

I have seen a post **[Google Maps Error: Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750692/google-maps-error-uncaught-invalidvalueerror-seticon-not-a-string-and-no-url)** with same issue and applied the change mentioned in the answer. Earlier it was working and now it also stopped working.

It Seems that google has changed something in their API but not sure what exactly. I found the same issue found by some other users too @ **https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7423**

My website link is **http://www.advantarealty.net/Search//Condo,Single-Family-Home,Townhome_PropertyType/True_ForMap/** just open in firefox and see the error console.
I have included below js files for map.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&libraries=drawing"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

<div id="map-canvas" class="map-view">hello</div>
```

Below is the complete javascript code which i used.

```
<script>
    var defaultLat = '@Html.Raw(Model != null && Model.Count() > 0 ? Convert.ToDouble(Model[0].Latitude) : 0)';
    var defaultLong = '@Html.Raw(Model != null && Model.Count() > 0 ? Convert.ToDouble(Model[0].Longitude) : 0)';
    if (defaultLat == 0)
        defaultLat = $('#SearchLatitude').val();
    if (defaultLong == 0)
        defaultLong = $('#SearchLongitude').val();

   // var json = JSON.parse('@str');

    // Add this for testing only
    var json = JSON.parse('[ { "DaysOnAdvanta": "400", "Name": null, "com_address": null, "MLS_ID": "miamimls", "MLS_STATE_ID": "FL", "MLS_LISTING_ID": "A1677437", "mls_office_id": null, "MLS_Office_Name": "EWM Realty International ", "MLS_AGENT_ID": null, "MLS_Agnet_Name": null, "SALE_PRICE": "400000", "Address": "5800 N BAY RD", "city": "Miami Beach", "zip_code": "33140", "remarks": "", "property_type_code": "Residential", "County": null, "Subdivision": "LA GORCE GOLF SUB PB 14-4", "status_code": "Active", "Year_Built": "1929", "acres": "0", "LOT_SQUARE_FOOTAGE": "52881", "BUILDING_SQUARE_FOOTAGE": "12153", "Bedroom_Count": "7", "Full_Baths": "8", "Half_Baths": null, "Fire_place_Number": null, "has_virtual_tour": null, "has_garage": null, "has_firepalce": null, "has_horses": null, "has_pool": null, "has_golf": null, "has_tennis": null, "is_gated": null, "is_waterfront": null, "has_photo": null, "photo_quantity": "25", "photo_url": null, "virtual_tour_url": "http://www.obeo.com/u.aspx?ID=630180", "last_updated": null, "listing_date": null, "garage": null, "last_image_transaction": null, "complex_building": null, "display_address": null, "advertise": null, "IMAGE": "/images/PhotoNotAvailable_Large.gif ", "visit": null, "inforequest": null, "FollwID": 0, "Latitude": "25.83835", "Longitude": "-80.13273", "Special": "", "price_change_direction": "", "location_id": "48153" } ]');
    // console.log(json);
    var contentString = "<div style='width: 200px; height: 250px;text-align: center;'>" +
        "<img src='//image6.sellectrified.com/flex/RX-3/113/RX-3113755-1.jpeg' width='200' alt='No Image' style='max-height: 130px;' />" +
        "<table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;'>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td style='text-align:left;height:20px;'>" +
                    "$155,000" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td style='text-align:right;height:20px;'>" +
                    "2754, Dora Ave" +
                "</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                    "<a href='javascript:void(0);'>" +
                        "<div class='btn btn-primary card-btn'>Details</div>" +
                    "</a>" +
                "</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "</table>" +
        "<table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;border-top:1px solid gray;'>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td style='text-align:center;font-size: 10px;'>" +
                    "2 BEDS" +
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                    "1 BATH" +
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                    "1,235 Sq.ft." +
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                "1.3 ACRE" +
                "</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "</table>" +
    "</div>";

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    var m = [];

    function initialize() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLat, defaultLong);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 8
            //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        if (json.length > 0) {
            $(json).each(function (i) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].Latitude, json[i].Longitude);
                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: latlng,
                    draggable: false,
                    raiseOnDrag: false,
                    map: map,
                    labelContent: "$" + (json[i].SALE_PRICE / 1000) + 'k',
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                    labelClass: "marker", // the CSS class for the label
                    icon: {},
                    title: json[i].Address,
                    id: json[i].MLS_ID + '-' + json[i].MLS_LISTING_ID
                });
                m.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                    var contentString = "<div style='width: 200px; text-align: center;'>" +
                                            "<img src='" + json[i].IMAGE + "' width='200' alt='' style='max-height: 130px;' />" +
                                            "<table style='width: 100%;'>" +
                                                "<tr>" +
                                                    "<td style='text-align:left;padding: 5px 0;'>" +
                                                         "$" + json[i].SALE_PRICE +
                                                    "</td>" +
                                                    "<td style='text-align:right;padding: 5px 0;'>" +
                                                        json[i].Address +
                                                    "</td>" +
                                                "</tr>" +
                                                "<tr>" +
                                                    "<td colspan='2' style='text-align:right;padding: 5px 0;'>" +
                                                        "<a class='orange-btn-small' href='/Home/PropertyDetail/" + json[i].location_id + "/" + json[i].MLS_ID + "/" + json[i].MLS_LISTING_ID + "/" + json[i].Address + "'>Details</a>" +
                                                    "</td>" +
                                                "</tr>" +
                                            "</table>" +
                                            "<table style='width: 100%; border-top:1px solid gray;'>" +
                                                "<tr>" +
                                                    "<td style='text-align:center;font-size: 10px;'>" +
                                                        json[i].Bedroom_Count + " BEDS" +
                                                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                                                       json[i].Full_Baths + " BATH" +
                                                    "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                                                        json[i].BUILDING_SQUARE_FOOTAGE + " Sq.ft." +
                                                    "</td>" +
                                                "</tr>" +
                                            "</table>" +
                                        "</div>";
                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    //getFocusLeftList(sn);
                });
                //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
                bounds.extend(marker.position);
            });
            //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: null,
            //drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                  google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
                ]
            },
            circleOptions: {
                fillColor: '#ffff00',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                clickable: false,
                editable: true,
                zIndex: 1
            }
        });
        //To add event on circle complete.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
            var radius = circle.getRadius();
            //alert(radius);
        });
        //To add event on drawing complete.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
            if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
                DrawCircleMarker(event.overlay);
                var radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
                //alert(radius);
            }
            else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE) {
                var cordinates = event.overlay.getBounds();
                // alert(cordinates);
            }
            else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
                var arrayPath = event.overlay.getPath().b;
                GetMaxMinLatLng(event.overlay);
                $('#Polygon').val(MasterPoly);
                changeView($('#map-canvas'), 'map');
            }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    var MaxLat = 0;
    var MaxLng = 0;
    var MinLat = 0;
    var MinLng = 0;
    var MasterPoly = '';
    var Polygon;
    function GetMaxMinLatLng(poly) {
        var polyPoints = poly.getPath();
        var oddNodes = false;
        if (Polygon != null)
            Polygon.setMap(null);
        Polygon = poly;
        for (var i = 0; i < polyPoints.getLength() ; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                MaxLat = polyPoints.getAt(i).lat();
                MaxLng = polyPoints.getAt(i).lng();
                MinLat = polyPoints.getAt(i).lat();
                MinLng = polyPoints.getAt(i).lng();
                var con = new Contour(polyPoints.j);
                var c = con.centroid();
                centerLat = c.y;
                centerLong = c.x;
                centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLong);
            }
            if (polyPoints.getAt(i).lat() > MaxLat) {
                MaxLat = polyPoints.getAt(i).lat();
                $('#SearchLatitude').val(MaxLat);
            }
            if (polyPoints.getAt(i).lat() < MinLat) {
                MinLat = polyPoints.getAt(i).lat();
            }
            if (polyPoints.getAt(i).lng() > MaxLng) {
                MaxLng = polyPoints.getAt(i).lng();
                $('#SearchLongitude').val(MaxLng);
            }
            if (polyPoints.getAt(i).lng() < MinLng) {
                MinLng = polyPoints.getAt(i).lng();
            }
        }
        MasterPoly = MinLng + ' ' + MaxLat + ',' + MinLng + ' ' + MinLat + ',' + MaxLng + ' ' + MinLat + ',' + MaxLng + ' ' + MaxLat + ',' + MinLng + ' ' + MaxLat;
    }

    function Point(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Contour object
    function Contour(points) {
        this.pts = points || []; // an array of Point objects defining the contour
    }

    Contour.prototype.area = function () {
        var area = 0;
        var pts = this.pts;
        var nPts = pts.length - 1;
        var j = nPts - 1;
        var p1; var p2;

        for (var i = 0; i < nPts; j = i++) {
            p1 = pts[i]; p2 = pts[j];
            area += p1.A * p2.k;
            area -= p1.k * p2.A;
        }
        area /= 2;
        return area;
    };

    Contour.prototype.centroid = function () {
        var pts = this.pts;
        var nPts = pts.length - 1;
        var x = 0; var y = 0;
        var f;
        var j = nPts - 1;
        var p1; var p2;

        for (var i = 0; i < nPts; j = i++) {
            p1 = pts[i]; p2 = pts[j];
            f = p1.A * p2.k - p2.A * p1.k;
            x += (p1.A + p2.A) * f;
            y += (p1.k + p2.k) * f;
        }

        f = this.area() * 6;

        return new Point(x / f, y / f);
    };

    $(".SearchProp").hover(function () {
        var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
        var long = $(this).attr("long");
        var sequence = $(this).attr("seq")
        google.maps.event.trigger(m[sequence], "mouseover");
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @geocodezip: I found your same comment on the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750692/google-maps-error-uncaught-invalidvalueerror-seticon-not-a-string-and-no-url although others were able to understand the problem.

Comment: Understanding the question and being provided enough information to efficiently answer it are two different things. That other question should probably be closed too.

Comment: @nathanchere: Did you understand both questions?

Comment: Completely irrelevant. I could ask you "how do I copy photos from my phone to my computer" and you'd understand the question immediately, but there is nowhere near enough information provided to efficiently answer it.

Comment: @nathanchere: The link i provided has much answers and one worked for me too earlier. IF you read it carefully you would get enough information to answer but if you only looking for a piece of code without reading the matter you can not understand from a "encyclopedia" too.

Comment: @nathanchere: I saw your profile and found that why my question is irrelevant for you. My question is related with google may and no related tag i found in your profile. :)

Comment: @nathanchere, I have understood the problem, this question is having enough details to understand even a novice user like me, I had faced the same issue and have resolved the issue, I have also posted my Answer below kindly check that out and accept my answer if it helps you. :)

Comment: Do you have something like this in your code?

`marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));`

Comment: Please share the JS Code you've written, just links to other post might not help.

Comment: No, I haven't written that code. Ok adding the code in the question now.

Comment: @SurjithSM: Added the code now, this might help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue.
Earlier markerwithlabel javascript library, if we want to hide the marker and only want to show the label, we just pass an empty braces to icon parameter like below

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: latlng,
                    draggable: false,
                    raiseOnDrag: false,
                    map: map,
                    labelContent: "$" + (json[i].SALE_PRICE / 1000) + 'k',
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                    labelClass: "marker", // the CSS class for the label
                    icon: {},
                    title: json[i].Address,
                    id: json[i].MLS_ID + '-' + json[i].MLS_LISTING_ID
                });
```

**icon: {},**

But now it doesn't work, you must have to supply an image icon for that. SO when I supplied a transparent image to icon, it works now.

```
icon: '/images/transparent-1x1.png',
```

Also I am now using latest js library for that

```
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.10/src/markerwithlabel.js
```

Comment: If I could give you the 50 points I would love to, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

I happened to fall in the same issue and below is the solution which helped me, I hope this helps you too.

First add this google marker with label script in a JS file- (mine is MarkerWithLabel.js)
https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js?r=131

Then add the below mentioned google map JS libraries on the page-

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=some_key_here&sensor=false
~/Scripts/MarkerWithLabel.js

```
function showMap() {
    var address = $('#corp-add').text();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                zoom: 16
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                draggable: true,
                raiseOnDrag: true,
                map: map,
                labelContent: "$425K",
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: { opacity: 0.75 }
            });
            var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "This is a test marker"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });
        }
    });
```

In my code above I am using Google GeoCoder to convert address to Latitudes and Longitudes. You can modify the above code according to your requirements.

You can also follow these links and they might be helpful-
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/examples.html

Let me know if you need more details from me.

Regards,

Manik

Comment: Do you have any working URL which shows Marker with Labels of your application?

Comment: It's not working for me, I can not see any difference between my and your code except libraries (which i also changed to check) and GeoCodes.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, i think you should share your entire code then only someone might be able to help you out..

Comment: I have added my code, this might help to understand the issue.